# An Integrate result is not what it should be

Tags: numerical-integration, algorithm

Recently, I come across an algorithm called **HyperLogLog** (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327004/how-does-the-hyperloglog-algorithm-work). There's a magic number in it, and when reading the [paper](https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/40671.pdf), I know it's an result of an integral:

$\alpha_m := (m \int_0^\infty(\log_2(\frac{2+u}{1+u}))^m\mathrm{d}u)^{-1}$

In Fig 1 of the paper, $\alpha_{16} = 0.673$, but when I calculate it in Mathematica, it returns $-0.0226255$. What am I missing?

My code is:

```
f[m_] := 1/(m Integrate[(Log[2, (2 + u)/(1 + u)])^m, {u, 0 , 
      Infinity}])
N[f[16]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why your approach evaluates without warning. NIntegrate

```
f[m_?NumericQ] := 1/(m NIntegrate[(Log[2, (2 + u)/(1 + u)])^m, {u, 0,Infinity}])
f[16] 
(*0.673102*)
```

solves your problem

Comment: I just ignore the warning... So NIntegrate can give the right result, cool!

Answer (score 8):

Also Integrate does the job right. The problem was N[f[16]].

Force N to wanted accuracy.

```
f[m_] := 1/(m Integrate[(Log[2, (2 + u)/(1 + u)])^m, {u, 0, Infinity}])

N[f[16], 10]

(*   0.6731020239   *)
```

Comment: You gave a tricky way to call NIntegrate with special accuracy I think, because `f[m]` can't be calculated analytically and therefor NIntegrate is called.

Comment: No. f[16] can easily be calculated analytically. Just do it. Result is to long to show as comment.

Comment: Ok you're right, I only looked at `f[m]`. But the question remains  why `N[f[16]]` gives such a poor numerical value.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann - because of the complexity of the analytic result and the fact that calculations done with machine precision neither track nor try to control the precision of the calculations. Machine precision is optimized for speed and should generally be checked against arbitrary precision calculations. Even arbitrary precision calculations may need to be checked for their sensitivity to changes in the amount of precision used.

Comment: Do `List @@ f[16][[3, 1]] // N ` to see,  `{5.33539*10^15, 3866.96, -5.33539*10^15} `  a very high positive value  of 10^15 is added to a very high negative value together with an intermediate value. Machine Precision looses some digits.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: Thank you for your explanation. I' m still wondering that many Numerical Functions work reliable... Just one point: Mathematica documentation says `N[expr] is equivalent to N[expr,MachinePrecision]`  which is obviously wrong in the example `N[f[16]]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann - I believe that the documentation is correct. Note that `N[f[16], MachinePrecision] == N[f[16]]` evaluates to `True` as expected from the documentation. If you are trying to get arbitrary precision to `$MachinePrecision` then use `N[f[16], $MachinePrecision]`. Compare `N[f[16], MachinePrecision] // Precision` to `N[f[16], $MachinePrecision] // Precision`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon:  The documentation says `The numerical value of MachinePrecision is $MachinePrecision` but `N[f[16], MachinePrecision] // Precision (* MachinePrecision *)` keeps unevaluated. So it should be good practice to avoid using  `N[]`-function without 2nd argument.? Thanks.